# Vps to laptop ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, vps, port-forwarding

I have a laptop that I use mostly as a desktop but occasionally it moves networks. I have a vps with a static address and I want to forward ports from the vps to the laptop so that I can get to the laptop from a public address even if the laptop is behind a router with no port forwarding setup.

Is this possible by running a command/script on the laptop at startup?

Everything is running Linux if that matters at all, I'm trying to forward minecraft traffic from a vps with public address and no memory to a laptop with lots of memory but no public address that occasionally moves to different networks. Is this possible with ssh somehow?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is creating a VPN (e.g. with OpenVPN). But you can use SSH, too.

```
ssh -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
```

You can automate this by using keys without passphrase but interrupted SSH connections are not restarted automatically. Thus it would be useful to make the SSH call from a loop. OpenVPN would be more useful though.

**Edit 1**

If you want to forward other remote addresses than localhost don't forget to both put

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

in the `sshd_config` file for the **server** and restart the server afterwards. You have to use one of these formats of the `ssh` command then:

```
-R 1.2.3.4:port:host:hostport
-R \*:port:host:hostport # the \  being for the shell only
-R :port:host:hostport
```

The `host` is an address on the **local** side (usually `localhost` or one of the other IP addresses of the host).

Comment: so it looks like an ssh reverse tunnel is what I'm looking for but I have an old OpenSSH (5.3) and it doesn't seem to let me bind the remote port to the public address. any ideas on that?

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos What was the command, what the result?

Comment: I run "ssh -R :25565:IP:25565 IP -N" where IP is the ip address of the vps and when I look at the vps I see a socket listening but only on localhost not the public interface.

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos The `IP` in `:25565:IP:25565` is wrong (or at least not the same as the other `IP` in the command); it must be a laptop's IP (including `localhost`). But that is probably not the problem: "Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5))."

Comment: so I should use ""ssh -R :25565:localhost:25565 IP -N"" then? and I've set GatewayPorts in the ssh_config file. Is there any way to see if it is in fact enabled?

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos `ssh -R \*:25565:localhost:25565 -N IP` And you have to set this option in **sshd_config** on the server (and restart it) not in **ssh_config** on the client.

Comment: I've set it on the server and restarted the service... and then the server and have tried the command in your last post no change. does ssh when I type "lsof -i | grep 25565" i see "sshd     663 serinox    9u  IPv4 95790761      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:25565 (LISTEN)" is it only listening on the vps's loopback? *** EDIt from the vps when I have the ssh tunnel open I can telnet into the minecraft server and it works. just not from the public address.

Comment: What have you written to the file, `GatewayPorts yes`? I just tried, works here that way. You can more easily check with `netstat -ln --inet`.

Comment: I wrote GatewayPorts yes to the file on its own line. When I run "netstat -ln --inet" i see "tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25565             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
" for the relevant port

Comment: @AvatarOfChronos That should be 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1. I have no good further idea what the problem may be. Are there maybe two "GatewayPorts" entries, one with `no` later overwriting yours? You should have a look at the logs on both sides (and increase the log level before).

Comment: I found the problem. I had an sshd_config that I thought it was using and it was loading another. It's working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

As Hauke Laging correctly noted - ssh connection may be interrupted.

You should use `autossh` to automatically start and restart tunnels on failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.ssh/config` file you can define a port forward like so:

```
Host alias
HostName 12.34.56.78
  [Port 12345]
  [User patrick]
  [LocalForward 6900 localhost:6900]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use dyndns on laptop?
Or you could add a small web script to VPS (the script would update firewall), and the laptop could request that page with wget/curl when starting up.
The script could be bash/shell script, and execute via ssh, but could be more complicated to find the connecting IP from a shell script (vs for example $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] )